# How do I get coloured output back for Cucumber in ConEmu?

Tags: cucumber, conemu

Cucumber gives coloured output in Windows 7 (64-bit) command prompt with ANSICON 1.6.0, but no longer in the ConEmu terminal manager.

**Cucumber**

- Cucumber.yml exists in \config folder
- Cucumber.yml contains `default: --color`

**ConEmu**

- Settings > Features > Inject ConEmuHk is checked
- Settings > Features > ANSI X3.64 / xterm 256 colors is checked
- `%ConEmuANSI%` returns `"ON"`
- `ls --color` does return coloured output
- Version status: 141004 preview

ConEmu appears to be fine, yet Cucumber appears to be configured correctly as well considering coloured output works in the command prompt. Any ideas?

Example output from Cucumber, as requested (these passing steps would previously show in green):

```
 Scenario: Visit the client site        # client\features\age_gate.feature:8
    Given I am a new visitor            # client/features/step_definitions/age_gate.rb:1
    When I visit the client website     # client/features/support/navigation.rb:1
    Then I am shown the age gate        # client/features/step_definitions/age_gate.rb:6
```

Comment: You've not shown what cucumber prints.

Comment: Thanks Maximus. Have edited the question with ConEmu version and example output (cannot show screenshots).

Comment: Three months old build? Really? Update to last alpha.

Comment: Wish something less simple would have fixed it, but that did it! Wonder what made it stop working, since I did have coloured output in that version for a while. Anyway, thanks for the solution and for ConEmu. When you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old build was used. Update to latest alpha.